# Couch DB replication - Sequence number in 'since' param is invalid

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase, cloudant

We have an android application which uses CouchBase Mobile. This application replicates from CouchDb on Cloudant.

We recently observed that (when replication started taking more than 6 minutes to 'complete') that the 'since' parameter sent in the 'changes' request is no where near the source's sequence number.

Source's SEQ = 66000+

Since param on 2nd and subsequent replication requests  = 25000+ (it varies)

We use a filter, which actually takes a lot of time,  and we are OK with it for the first replication. But we see that future replications takes 6 minutes (even when there are no updates at source  db).

We suspect that for the filtered replication the target only makes a checkpoint for the last replicated doc and *not* the source's commit sequence.

Is this the default behaviour? Is there a way to overcome this feature/problem?

[We are in the process of migrating to CouchDB Lite, but we need to fix this before that].

Regards,

Vijay

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We have a similar problem where the `since` parameter is incorrectly set by couchbase lite when we repeat filtered replication with different settings.